# How to return all users that have access to a specific record

Tags: apex, rest-api, permissions, permission-sets

Is it in any way possible to return a list of users that have access to a specific record together with their permissions?

What I want to do is the equivalent of the SOQL query

```
SELECT RecordId, UserId, MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE RecordId = '0010Y00000YHrBdQAL'
```

This query won't work since UserId cannot be selected. It is also not possible to filter on a list of users ids in that query (see the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm#!))

According to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95246/52541) answer the reason why the above query doesn't work is that UserRecordAccess is a view and not a table. I would like to emulate the functionality of that view without making too many calls to Salesforce.

My current solution for collecting users with access to specific account records is to use the following SOQL queries

```
// [1] Collect ids of permission sets that have access to any accounts
SELECT ParentId 
FROM ObjectPermissions 
WHERE SobjectType='Account'

// [2] Collect all the users that are part of the permission sets returned in query 1
SELECT AssigneeId, PermissionSetId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE PermissionSetId IN <Ids of the collected permission sets>

// [3] For each user id returned in query 3 do the following query
SELECT MaxAccessLevel
FROM UserRecordAccess 
WHERE UserId = <The current user id> AND RecordId = '0010Y00000YHrBdQAL'

// [4] Join the user id and the MaxAccessLevel and return that
```

The problem here is of course that step 3 has to be repeated for each user that is part of a permission set with access to accounts. This could potentially be a lot of users. And as far as I understand this won't even give me all users with access to the requested record if there are special sharing rules in place.

Is it in any way possible to simplify this process either through SOQL or by using APEX to create a custom REST endpoint?

From what I can see in the discussion to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107519/how-to-query-users-who-have-access-to-a-particular-record) question there does not seem to be any good ways to do it, but I hope the situation has changed since that question was asked.

Comment: Why do you need this information? What are you trying to achieve at a high level here? Have you tried investigating the [`AccountShare`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountshare.htm) table?

Comment: We are using the Salesforce data in another external system where it is combined with data from other sources. The reason why we need permissions per object is to make sure that if we at some point "promote" an object to primarily be stored in our system we still keep the correct permission levels. Calls to the `AccountShare` table do not return anything. It just returns an empty list so I think I can't use that.